# Only one selected element out of those used is working

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, dom-events

I have selected elements using the `DOM`. an input `type="text"` and some input `type="radio"`. I want to be able to enter the answer or click on the aforementioned elements and get the code block to run the code within when the (submit) button is clicked.

Please Help! I have tried and failed to come up with a solution to this issue.

```
//Images, button and empty div
let regImage = document.getElementById("img1");
let correctImage = document.getElementById("img2");
let incorrectImage = document.getElementById("img3");
let passedImage = document.getElementById("img4");
let failedImage = document.getElementById("img5");
let resultBox = document.getElementById("result-box");
let submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit");


//this is the <input type="text">
let q1 = document.querySelector("#text-field");

//these are radio buttons <input type="radio">
let answerOne = document.querySelector("#q2-answer1");
let answerTwo = document.querySelector("#q2-answer2");
let answerThree = document.querySelector("#q3-answer1");
let answerFour = document.querySelector("#q3-answer2");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let clicked = false;
  switch(clicked === false) {
    case q1.value === "1950" || answerOne || answerThree:
      regImage.style.display = "none";
      correctImage.style.visibility = "visible";
      resultBox.textContent = "1 Correct";
    break;
  }
})
```

q1.value works well but when (answerOne) and (answerThree) is chosen and the submit button is clicked nothing happens.

Comment: does the F12 > Console display any error messages when answerOne or answerThree is clicked?

Comment: What is the point of the `switch` with a single `case`? Also, `switch` is not `if`, the `case`in the code compares to `true`.  See how [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) works.

Comment: What do you mean by `case q1.value == "1950" || answerOne || answerThree:`? `answerOne` and `answerThree` are DOM elements, they're always truthy (unless the elements don't exist).

Comment: Maybe you meant `case q1.value == "1950" || answerOne.checked || answerThree.checked:`?

Comment: No, there were no error message when they were clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Using `switch` for this is inappropriate IMHO. Just use normal `if` and `else if` for multiple cases.

The problem with your code is that you're not testing whether the radio buttons are selected.

```
if (q1.value == "1950" || answerOne.checked || answerThree.checked) {
    regImage.style.display = "none";
    correctImage.style.visibility = "visible";
    resultBox.textContent = "1 Correct";
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks man! I didn't know about this(.checked) property before this. My code works now.